# How do I find out which process is using so much of my RAM?

Tags: linux, memory, vmware

I am running a cassandra instance on a server with 16GB RAM. The process has crashed after an OutOfMemory error.

Now, when I check the memory usage, 11GB out of 16GB is used.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         16056      11032       5024          0          4         23
-/+ buffers/cache:      11004       5052
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Dropping caches by echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches is not helping.

This is the output of the top command with PIDs sorted by RAM usage:

[image]

I am not getting which processes are eating up the memory. Am I missing something here?

How can I recover the lost memory?

Following is the CPU detail:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             4
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 44
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2933.437
BogoMIPS:              5866.87
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              15360K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

uname -a:
`Linux ExpressoBDAPp33133 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 27 15:55:46 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Why do you think processes are eating up the memory? Nothing in your `top` output suggests that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Output of `free` is not aligned properly.  Total memory is 16056 and used is 11032.

Comment: Even in `top` output, the overall used memory is 11299340K without any significant process running. Is there a better way to find out the actual memory usage.

Comment: You're not really making sense. Do you have some reason to believe the memory is being used by processes? If so, what is that reason? If not, why are you trying to figure out what process is using the memory?

Comment: If you watch the `top` output, the total memory used by individual processes does not add up to the total Used memory. It all boils down to one single question that how can I free up the RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are running inside VMware:

```
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
```

You should check how much memory you are allocating to each guest. If you are allocating more memory than the host has (overcommitment), and the host is running out of memory, it'll start [ballooning](http://www.vfrank.org/2013/09/18/understanding-vmware-ballooning/) - basically, it'll start taking up space in the guests (forcing the guests to start swapping) so the hypervisor has more memory to work with.

In fact, the default max balloon amount is supposedly 65% of the guest's physical memory. That fits rather perfectly with your 11 GB of 16 GB used.

Ballooning will appear as used memory in the guest - and since it's performed by a kernel-mode driver, it won't appear as a process. This can have side effects: if you have disabled swap, the guest OS will simply refuse any requests for more memory than is available.

Note that ballooning is a *symptom* of a much bigger problem: lack of resources on the host. Do not simply disable ballooning, since that'll force the hypervisor to start swapping out guest memory, completely killing performance. You should instead either set memory reservations for this guest (which will force the hypervisor to more aggressively reclaim memory from other guests), and set some swap so the guest can swap out least-used pages intelligently when ballooning happens, instead of forcing the hypervisor to do so randomly.

You can also check how much memory is "used" by ballooning from [within the guest](https://serverfault.com/questions/660080/detect-memory-ballooning-from-within-the-affected-vm). If this is occurring, you need more physical resources - either upgrade the host, or spread the VMs over more hosts.

See also, the [VMware white paper on memory management](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/perf-vsphere-memory_management.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The memory is not lost and does not need to be recovered. It is in use.

Free memory is wasted. It provides no benefit. If you're thinking "I want that memory free now so it can be used later", that's ridiculous. You can use memory now *and* use it later. In fact, having memory free now just makes it harder to use it later because if memory is free, it takes effort to use it.

There's no tradeoff to be made here. You can't use less RAM today so you can use more RAM tomorrow. RAM can't be saved. Nothing is wrong. There is nothing to fix.

Modern operating systems only make memory free if they have absolutely no other choice. There is *no* advantage to having memory free. Only memory that is in use provides a benefit, and free memory takes effort to use.

Do not think that memory must be free to be available. The vast majority of used memory is typically available on modern operating systems. Memory can be directly transitioned from one use to another without the wasted effort of having to make it free in the meantime.

Comment: I want to add that the paper "DRAM Errors in the Wild - a Large-Scale Field Study" (Schroeder, Pinheiro, Weber; SIGMETRICS/Performance’09) finds that there exists a positive correlation between a high amount of allocated memory and single bitflips (correctable by ECC). This could indeed be seen as a disadvantage.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I agree with you. But my question is in some other direction. Sorry if I am not able to explain the problem clearly. As you said, the memory is in use, I just want to know where this memory is getting used.

Comment: @dvl It can be anything. It can, for example, be cached copies of directories. Why does it matter?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It matters because the JVM process is not able to allocate enough RAM to start the program.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the output of `free` has slightly misaligned titles. The used memory is 11GB. Please also refer to `top` output.  And I still do not know where is this memory getting used.